# Angular Sticky header, content on scrolling not disappearing into header, still showing

Tags: css, angular

I read the post here on sticky headers and have the following Angular layout

```
<div fxLayout="column">
    <div class="sticky">
        <app-header></app-header>
        <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    </div>
 
    <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="100">
        <div class="my-content">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
   
    </div>
</div>
```

I added the sticky css to have the header and navbar stay at the top even when scrolling and that works

```
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;  
    top: 0;  
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But when I scroll and the main content is moving up. The content does not disappear into the header, I can still see the labels, textboxes, and grid.

I added my-content and added the overflow but it still not working.

```
.my-content {
    padding: 0 15px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

I been go over this post many times and don't see how the content hides under the banner

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-0-0-rc-1-ccgxry?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your provided link is working fine I think. Can you explain little more with some image what is your problem and what you want to do? Because I can see content disappeared into the header.

Comment: Sorry, the link was an example I am following. My header has a image as the banner. I also tried to apply to the header, background: inherit; and background: fixed; Neither of those help. From the working example, the scrolling works and it scrolls and disapear into the header. I can't get mine to do that. Thanks

Comment: When I scroll up, i can see the table over the banner, I am trying to get it to have the visual effect of moving under the header.

Answer (score 0):

finally figure out the answer, add z-index

```
.header-sticky {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;  
    z-index: 10;
    background:inherit;
}

.my-content {
    padding: 0 15px;
    width: 100%;
z-index:5;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```